# regex maven packagingExcludes

Tags: regex, maven, maven-plugin

I m trying to use the packagingExcludes with a regular expression but it doesn't work for me.

When i make mvn package, i have two Jars included :

- mtm-common-lib-1.0.8.jar
- mtm-common-lib-3.0.9-20160113.031644-18-jboss.jar

I want to take only the Jar with *name* **-jboss.jar** extention.

I've tried like this :

```
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
 .........
 .........
 <packagingExcludes>
  ......,
  ......,
 %regex[WEB-INF/lib/mtm-common-lib-*-(?!jboss).jar]
 </packagingExcludes>
```

And also :

```
 %regex[WEB-INF/lib/mtm-common-lib*(?!mtm-common-lib*jboss.jar).jar]
 %regex[WEB-INF/lib/mtm-common-lib*(?!jboss).jar]
```

none works for me.

any clue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%regex[WEB-INF/lib/mtm-common-lib-(.(?!-jboss))*.jar]
```

The idea is to match multiple characters, checking after each character that `-jboss` doesn't follow.

Comment: I tried your answer but it seems  that it does the opposite, it removes the mtm-common-lib-3.0.9-20160113.031644-18-jboss.jar and keep mtm-common-lib-1.0.8.jar.

Comment: @Kikou, sorry, I didn't see it was in `packagingExcludes`. Updated.

Comment: thxs , but %regex[WEB-INF/lib/mtm-common-lib-.*-(?<!jboss).jar] doesn't work either, because  "<" at (?<!jboss), generate "unexpected character in markup"

Comment: doesn't work too , i want to find the best regular expression , in the meaning take only jar with names that begin with mtm-common-lib and contains -jboss even if there is an already jar mtm-common-lib without -jboss. so if there is two Jar , we must take the Jar with -jboss extention for the same jar name.